# FPDF with python : Some Japanese characters are showing as rectangle

Tags: python, fonts, fpdf, cjk

I try to print a simple japanese word in a pdf. I modified a basic exemple to see if it would work but not what I expected to see.

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()


# Add a AR PL New Sung Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
# The Open Source Chinese Font (also supports other east Asian languages)
pdf.add_font('fireflysung', '', 'fireflysung.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font('fireflysung', '', 14)
pdf.write(8, u'Chinese: 你好世界\n')
pdf.write(8, u'Japanese: こんにちは世界\n')
pdf.write(8, u'bicycle: 自転車 (ジテンシャ)\n')
pdf.ln(10)

pdf.output("unicode.pdf")
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkAF2.png)

Expected:

> Japanese: 自転車 (ジテンシャ)

How do I display this missing character ?

Edit:

> So I found a [font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-jpan) that seams to work for now. I converted it to .ttf using [otf2tff](https://pypi.org/project/otf2ttf/). Hope it will help.

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question but does the font you are using have that character in it?

Comment: It might be that. I've search for other fonts before but I couldn't find any working.